# How to use angular 'filter' filter when repeated values are also filtered?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am writing an angular ng-repeat expression as follows

```
<tr ng-repeat='instance in instances | filter : search'>
    <td>{{$index}}</td>
    <td>{{instance.Duration | duration}}</td>
    <td>{{instance.Start | mediumDate}}</td>
</tr>
```

The duration filter is a custom filter that I wrote. It converts the number of seconds to number of days. For example, if instance.Duration is 172800, then the filtered value will be 2 (i.e. 172800/(24*60*60))

Now the problem is, the ng-repeat filter is still applied for the original value(i.e 172800).

How can I make the ng-repeat 'filter' filter to filter results based on the 'duration' filtered results?

Here is a fiddle to show the issue 
http://jsfiddle.net/pupudu/00qegfkc/

Comment: can you show demo in jsfiddle?

Comment: @DashangG.Makwana Here is a fiddle as u suggested http://jsfiddle.net/pupudu/00qegfkc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one more object named formattedInstances, which will be copy of Instances, but Duration and Start will be formatted (same format which you get after applying filter). Use this formattedInstances in ng-repeat.

Comment: Good answer. But I don't want to repeat twice for the same purpose